# How can i add a class e.g 'active' in one of these < li >, one at a time with up and down key press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, treeview

I tried making a pointer to first li and then tried navigating through it but not working in my case:
[this is the pic of my dom element ][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1uO6.png
```

Code:

```
 $(window).keyup(function(e) {
                console.log("Key Code: ", e.keyCode);
                var $currentParent = $('div[data-tree-model] li.active');
                console.log("Current Parent", $currentParent);
                var $next;
                if (e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 37) {
                    $currentParent[0].firstElementChild.click();
                   
                } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
                    $next = $currentParent.prev();
                } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                    $next = $currentParent.next();
                }

                if ($next.length > 0) {
                    $('div[data-tree-model] li ').removeClass('active');
                    $next.addClass('active');
                }
            });
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text." + "**Describe the problem.** "not working" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it"_

Comment: seems to be working https://jsfiddle.net/xan6sorL/. I only changed this line from `if ($next.length > 0) {` to `if ($next && $next.length > 0) {`.

Comment: yea , do you have idea if i want to jump from parent li to inside sub li like a tree structure and then again perform this navigation to sub li